# Obj[] Vs. Observable<Obj[]> Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, observable

This might be a question with too obvious answers, but I didn't find a good answer for this.

Say I have an array of objects type 'Obj'( `Obj[]` Vs. `Observable<Obj[]>` ) for binding data using *ngFor.

What is the difference/advantages in following scenarios:

1. When Obj list is returned as an HTTP response and being frequently updated
2. When Obj list is returned as an HTTP response and being updated only once
3. When it is a secondary array(not populated via an HTTP) but updated by another array

What's the recommended way in Angular and why?

Code:

```
//declaration
private contests: Observable<Contest[]>;
private dayPlanCandidates: Observable<Contest[]>;

//populate
    let response = this.contestService.search(this.query, page, size, sort);
    this.contests = response.map(p => p.content);

//http call
return this.http.get(targetUrl, { params: params })
            .share()
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map(pageObj => Page.build(pageObj, Contest.from));

<!-- binding-->
<div *ngFor="let contest of contests | async"> </div>
<div *ngFor="let contest of dayPlanCandidate"> </div>
```

As you can see in the code, there are 2 Observable arrays.

1. contests array is directly updated from an http response
2. dayPlanCandidates array depends on contests.

My questions: 
If I should keep both arrays as observables or
if I should keep the contests[] as an observable and set the dayPlanCandidates to just a Contest array?

Comment: Questions should show the code, what you have tried, what you expected, what went wrong

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Nothing went wrong, I just want to know, out of array and observable array what's recommended way and why.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good place for recommendations because there is not a single correct answer. For open ended questions, you can try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ Again, if you add some code and explain what your concern is specifically, we could help; open ended questions are too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Observable` is 'simply' an object which behaves as a wrapper around asynchronous data, or "data that will come at a later time." This is part of the `RxJS` library (or `RX` in general, which stands for: reactive extensions.) This 3rd party library is integrated into Angular and is a "common" object which allows you to manipulate asynchronous values pretty nicely (once you get the hang of it, steep learning curve though.) - To be fair, I got away with building an ENTIRE angular project without worrying about `Observables` (and types)

It is better to use the async pipe with `Observables`, as Angular is designed to consume these objects pretty nicely (saves you a LOT of boilerplate code)